# Finding a sum of unique triplet that is close to a given number in an array

Tags: java, programming-challenge

I asked one question on code review yesterday about my code style, logic and readability of code. Hence, today I kept all those suggestions in mind while solving a new problem question.

The question is such: Given an array S of n integers, find three integers in S such that the sum is closest to a given number, target. Return the sum of the three integers. You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution.

For example: given array S = {-1 2 1 -4}, and target = 1.
The sum that is closest to the target is 2. (-1 + 2 + 1 = 2).

This is my solution:

```
 public int threeSumClosest(int[] num, int target) {
    if(num.length < 3) {
        return 0;
    }
      Arrays.sort(num);
    int tempSum = Math.abs( target - ( num[0] + num[1] + num[2] ));
    int result = num[0] + num[1] + num[2];

    for (int index = 0; index < num.length - 1; index++) {
        int j = index + 1;
        int k = num.length-1;
        while (j < k){
            int newSum = Math.abs( target - ( num[index] + num[j] + num[k] ) );
            if( newSum == 0 ) {
                return ( num[index] + num[j] + num[k] ) ;
            }
            else if ( num[index] + num[j] + num[k] < target ) {
                if( newSum < tempSum ) {
                    tempSum = newSum;
                    result = num[index] + num[j] + num[k];
                }

                j++;
            }
            else {
                if( newSum < tempSum ) {
                    tempSum = newSum;
                    result = num[index] + num[j] + num[k];
                }
                k--;
            }
        }//end of while loop
    }// end of for loop
    return result;
}
```

It would be great to hear back if I need to make further improvements. Any help will be highly appreciated. Also, Is there an approach which can solve this problem in less than \$O(n^2)\$.

Answer (score 4):

### Algorithm - Reducing search space

I'd define `kMax` as `num.length - 1`.

Then, do a binary search for the point at which `num[0] + num[1] + num[k - 1]` is too low, and `num[0] + num[1] + num[k]` is too high. Set `kMax` to `k`.

Next, do a binary search for the point at which `num[i] + num[kMax - 1] + num[kMax]` is too high, and `num[i - 1] + num[kMax - 1] + num[kMax]` is too low. Define `iMin` to be `i - 1`.

Start your for loop loop with `index` at `iMin`. At the start of each iteration, set `k` to `kMax`.

Instead of your current moving up/moving down scheme, just start downing k. As long as `[i][j][k-1]` is too high, `kMax` = `k`. When `[i][j][k-1]` is no longer too high, resume your uppy-downy scheme.

Whenever you increment `i`, check if `[i][k-1][k]` is too low. If so, increase i until `[i][k-1][k]` is no longer too low. Check if `[i-1][k-1][k]` gives a better match and store it as temp.

AFter changing scope like this, check the opposite end of the scope. So if you just reduced `k`, check if `[i][k-1][k]` is too low. If you just increased `i`, check if `[i][i+1][k]` is too high. Do this until scope is stable.

Perhaps binary search could speed this (upping i and downing k) up too, but I'm not sure.

What this would do is potentially eliminate is a lot of your search space.

You see, if I gave you the number 42 to find in an array that contained random numbers between -500 and +200, -500, +199, +200 is simply too low. So you can kill off any number that's below -357, provided it's not the last number at or below -357.

This is a reduction of 20% of your search space with a simple binary search.

Additionally, once we get to -70, any number greater than 182 that is not the last number at or above 182 is not going to help.

---

Binary search is blazingly fast. 10000 elements can be searched through in 13-14 array accesses. 100000 elements - 17 array accesses.

Consider stopping binary search when your scope size is less than 128 (your code should go blazingly fast at that point anyway).

### Your code

`for (int index = 0; index < num.length - 1; index++)`

For an array of 3 elements... `index < num.length - 1` means `index < 3 - 1` means `index < 2`.

So you've got a problem; You'll eventually check `[1][2][2]`. Your fix for this is `while(j < k)`, but I think you'll be better served by changing the for loop header to be `for (int index = 0; index < num.length - 2; index++)` (changing `index < num.length - 1` to `index < num.length - 2`). And then adding a comment WHY it is 2.

```
        int newSum = Math.abs( target - ( num[index] + num[j] + num[k] ) );
        if( newSum == 0 ) {
            return ( num[index] + num[j] + num[k] ) ;
        }
        else if ( num[index] + num[j] + num[k] < target ) {
            //code
            result = num[index] + num[j] + num[k];
```

You have here, in a single iteration, 2 to 3 summations of `num[index] + num[j] + num[k]`. Some languages will cache these values. Some languages will not. I'd get in the habit of summing them once, then doing what you must.

```
        else if ( num[index] + num[j] + num[k] < target ) {
            if( newSum < tempSum ) {
                tempSum = newSum;
                result = num[index] + num[j] + num[k];
            }

            j++;
        }
        else {
            if( newSum < tempSum ) {
                tempSum = newSum;
                result = num[index] + num[j] + num[k];
            }
            k--;
        }
```

Haaang on.

I think you can unduplicate your code here:

```
        else {
            if( newSum < tempSum ) {
                tempSum = newSum;
                result = num[index] + num[j] + num[k];
            }
            if(num[index] + num[j] + num[k] < target){
                k--;
            } else {
                j++;
            }
        }
```

Combine it with the idea of making the sum variable and you get the following:

```
        int sum = num[index] + num[j] + num[k];
        if( sum == 0 ) {
            return sum;
        }
        else {
            int newSum = Math.abs( target - sum );                
            if( newSum < tempSum ) {
                tempSum = newSum;
                result = sum;
            }
            if(sum < target){
                k--;
            } else {
                j++;
            }
        }
```

Additionally, `Math.abs` is not yet required for your first if. So leaving that one out until it's needed speeds things up a bit.

And since a return statement exits the function, we can use an implicit else:

```
        int sum = num[index] + num[j] + num[k];
        if( sum == 0 ) {
            return sum;
        }
        int newSum = Math.abs( target - sum );                
        if( newSum < tempSum ) {
            tempSum = newSum;
            result = sum;
        }
        if(sum < target){
            k--;
        } else {
            j++;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the first bit of code:

```
if(num.length < 3) {
        return 0;
    }
```

## Naming

- `minimumInputArrayLength = 3` and would be helpful to someone skimming the code.
- `inputArray` is probably a more descriptive name than `num`.

## Magic Numbers

The immediate caller has to handle what is essentially an exception and to handle it in a form other than `try...catch`. It also precludes the caller from allowing the exception to bubble up to what may be a more appropriate higher level.

All the worse because there's no way to distinguish a good zero from a bad zero.

For example: given an array S = {-1 2 1 -3}, and target = 1:

- `result` could be zero at the end of the computation.

A little less worse, but still a potential source of cognitive overhead for the programmer using the function:

- `result` could be 2 at the end of the computation depending on the behavior of the sort function.
- A specification would help, but probably not be consulted until bugs were experienced.

Down the road, the dependency on sorting by `<` or `>` ought to be made explicit so that a maintainer of the code is less likely to change it and thereby breaking code that depends on implementation details.